# How to access Notification.when field in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-notifications

How to access Android Notification object's Notification.when field in Kotlin?

`when` is a keyword in Kotlin so `notify.when` causes Syntax Error on Android Studio.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#when)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the back apostrophes.

```
val notification = Notification()
notification.`when`
```

Link to documentation - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin